# D3 x axis Formatting

Tags: d3.js

I want to format the x axis text with more padding and space and I am not able to achieve this. The actual text is around 6-7 characters long, but it is only showing 3.  Here is the extract of the code and a screenshot:

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis)
.selectAll("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(90)");
```

[d3 bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NZLL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rotating the text in the ticks, you have to set the `x` and `y`. Also, it's a good idea changing the `text-anchor`. Something like this:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)//tweak this value
    .attr("x", 10)//tweak this value
    .attr("dy", ".35em")//tweak this value
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");
```

Check the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 100);

var data = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "foobaz"];

var scale = d3.scaleBand()
 .range([0, 400])
 .domain(data);
 
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,30)")
    .call(axis)
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)//tweak this value
    .attr("x", 10)//tweak this value
    .attr("dy", ".35em")//tweak this value
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .attr("font-size", 14)
    .style("text-anchor", "start");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gerardo.  I still wasn't able to get this to work.  I think I have some issue with the height. http://codepen.io/smerchant/pen/RobQWv

Comment: @SMerchant your codepen is not working. Please paste a working code, and I'll have a look on it.

Comment: Sorry, can you please try this one. http://plnkr.co/edit/gT7DMWMNuSrp3BIrIsi0?p=preview

Comment: @SMerchant your numbers are too big, it's just a matter of adjusting the bottom margin: http://plnkr.co/edit/9JUs52XlUOL6YJ6s2Y8V?p=preview