# D3.js Adjust labels closer to each other

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm graphing data with long Y-axis labels (temperature ranges).  How do I adjust the labels so that they're centered on the ticks when they're rotated 90 degrees and don't run off the edge of the graph?  I've attempted to use this.getBBox() to apply a transform based on the iteration of the label, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    
    .axis text {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    var margin = {top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    var categories = {
                    temperature: ["29-30°C - Red","31-33° C - Green","> 33° C - Blue"],
                    sleep: ["7 - 8 hours", "5 - 6 hours", "4 or less hours"]
                    }
    
    var mindate = new Date(2012,0,1),
                maxdate = new Date(2012,0,31);
    
    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([mindate, maxdate])    // values between for month of january
            .range([0, width - margin.right]);
    
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .orient("bottom")
                .scale(xScale);
    
    var yKey = "temperature";
    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(categories[yKey])
        .rangePoints([0, height]);
    
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left");
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "yAxis axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
         .attr("x", 10)
         .attr("y",20)
         .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
         .style("text-anchor", "start")
    </script>
```

Here's what I've tried but this doesn't seem to move the labels much.  I'm not sure how to set the "x" inside the following function without using a translate.

```
d3.selectAll(".yAxis text")
        .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
          return "translate(" + -20 + "," + ((this.getBBox().width/(i+2))) + ")rotate(-90)"
        })
```

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, my answer here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40370554/5768908

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! The answer is that d3.scale.ordinal has a padding setting, so all I have to do is change my yScale to

```
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(categories[yKey])
            .rangePoints([0, height],1);
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    
    .axis text {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    var margin = {top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    var categories = {
                    temperature: ["29-30°C - Red","31-33° C - Green","> 33° C - Blue"],
                    sleep: ["7 - 8 hours", "5 - 6 hours", "4 or less hours"]
                    }
    
    var mindate = new Date(2012,0,1),
                maxdate = new Date(2012,0,31);
    
    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([mindate, maxdate])    // values between for month of january
            .range([0, width - margin.right]);
    
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .orient("bottom")
                .scale(xScale);
    
    var yKey = "temperature";
    var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(categories[yKey])
        .rangePoints([0, height],1);
    
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left");
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "yAxis axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
         .attr("x", 10)
         .attr("y",20)
         .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
         .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    </script>
```