# How to rotate X tick labels in D3 normalized stacked barchart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am just starting learning D3. Now I am making a [normalized stacked barchart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886394) using D3. My data set is very similar to `data.csv` given in the example. Just instead of 7 categories, I have only 2 of them.

My question is how to rotate xtick labels (e.g. set to 90 degree)? It is especially useful when labels text is quite long.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.1)
    .align(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#9467BD","#ff6666"]);

var stack = d3.stack()
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand);

d3.csv("data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b[data.columns[1]] / b.total - a[data.columns[1]] / a.total; });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Group; }));
  z.domain(data.columns.slice(1));

  var serie = g.selectAll(".serie")
    .data(stack.keys(data.columns.slice(1))(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "serie")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });

  serie.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.Group); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "%"));

  var legend = serie.append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { var d = d[d.length - 1]; return "translate(" + (x(d.data.Group) + x.bandwidth()) + "," + ((y(d[0]) + y(d[1])) / 2) + ")"; });

  legend.append("line")
      .attr("x1", -6)
      .attr("x2", 6)
      .attr("stroke", "#000");

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", 9)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
});

function type(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

I tried to add this block of code, but then all labels just disappear:

```
  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");
```

UPDATE:

```
Group,VAL 1,VAL 2
XXX XXXXXXXXXXXX,24983,66605
YYY XXXXXXXXXXXX,13522,61334
AAA XXXXXXXXXXXX,15289,37347
BBB XXXXXXXXXXXX,13155,38813
CCC XXXXXXXXXXXX,8374,22656
GGG XXXXXXXXXXXX,7660,21879
ABC XXXXXXXXXXXX,7935,16870
TTT XXXXXXXXXXXX,4831,18409
DDD XXXXXXXXXXXX,6301,16371
ZZZ XXXXXXXXXXXX,7207,13617
YYY XXXXXXXXXXXX,4407,15845
XX2 XXXXXXXXXXXX,3989,15031
FXX XXXXXXXXXXXXGC,3260,13754
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 x axis Formating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369877/d3-x-axis-formating)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Please see my update. Also, the link that you provided tells nothing about the legend (my second sub-question).

Comment: Please, make just **one** question per post. You can always post a new question with the second issue.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Please see my new update. I posted a sample data. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why the labels disappeared for you. They look ok to me: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/5pknyzub/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: I copied-pasted your solution, and in fact I see that the lables are rotated, however in my case the text is cropped. I can only see first 3-4 characters. Do you know why does it happen?

Comment: That's because you didn't change the bottom margin. Check the bottom margin in my fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131587/discussion-between-dinosaurius-and-gerardo-furtado).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Ok, now it works! Thanks!